# Applescript Automator default text field value

Tags: xcode, applescript, automator

i'm trying to make an automator action to rename files to my specific needs.
that's 3 text field, one for the date in YYYYMMDD format, one of the project I'm working on and one for the filename itself.

so i've figured everything out so far except this specific question/task.

is it possible to set a textfield to a default value whenever it's run?
in this case it would be the date field to "today"

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you are asking for Applescript but you can do this all simply by using some Automator Actions.

1,  **Get Selected Finder Items** is used with the assumption you are running this as a workflow and not a Service.

This gets the selected Finder items and passes them onto the next action as a List.

### [image]

2,**Set Value of Variable** Action.

This captures the Selected Items from the Action above.

We will use this later. I have name this variable: **theFiles**.

### [image]

3, **Ask for Text** action.

When the workflow runs this will popup a dialogue where you can enter the **Project Name**.

Make sure you set this to **ignore input** from the Action above.
( crtl+click the action to get the contextual menu. Select **ignore input**)

[image]

---

4, **Set Value of Variable** Action.

Use this to capture the above actions input .i.e the **Project Name**.

I have name this variable: **theProjectName**.

### [image]

5, **Get Value of Variable** Action.

We now need to get and pass on the file list to the next action So we get it with this action by selecting the  variable: **theFiles**. from it's dropdown menu.

Make sure you set this to **ignore input** from the Action above.
( crtl+click the action to get the contextual menu. Select **ignore input**)

[image]

---

6,  **Rename Finder Items**:

This is where we add the Project name to the files passed onto this action.

We set this action to:

- Add: **Add Text**

  - **Before name**

In the **Add:** field we can drag the blue token of the  variable: **theProjectName** into it.

We can also add a space and a hyphen or any other text after the token. (As shown)

[image]

---

7, **Rename Finder Items**:

This is where we add the **Date** to the files passed onto this action.

We set this action to:

- **Add Date or Time**
- Date/Time: **Current**

  - Where : **Before name**
  - separator :  **space** ( or whatever you choose)
- Format : **Year Month Day**

  - separator :  **dash** ( or whatever you choose)

[image]

---

How it all Looks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **Rename Finder Items** Action will add the Date to the filename, but only in the formats that it has pre-defined.  If you want the format YYYYMMDD, you need to define your own Text variable using a **Run AppleScript** Action:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set rightNow to (current date)

    set theYear to rightNow's year as text
    set theMonth to rightNow's month as number as text
    set theDay to rightNow's day as text

    return (theYear & theMonth & theDay)
end run
```

I believe that this will work best as the first Action of the Workflow, which will then feed to **Set Value of Variable**, and then you can add that text to any portion of the filename you wish.